# SSL Configuration in OHS 12c

Tags: ssl, weblogic12c, oracle-http-server

In the past, my web application hosted in Weblogic 12c and OHS 12c, the url is http://serverName/webName

SSL is pretty new to me, now I managed to turn on

```
1. SSL in Weblogic, web application can access through https://serverName:7002/webName
2. SSL in OHS virtual host on port 4443, vertified using https://serverName:4443
```

Now I am having challenge making my web application accessible through https://serverName:4443/webName or https://serverName/webName. Need guidance on how to edit OHS configuration (ssl.conf, mod_wl_ohs.conf, httpd.conf, etc) to achieve above.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to enrich your mod_wl_ohs.conf with the following 2 directives :
        SecureProxy ON
        WLSSLWallet "/path/to/wallet/directory/as/defined/in/your/ssl/conf/file"
You may find more details on these directives here :
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/web.1111/e10144/directives.htm#CIHFAAJB

But if you would like for the "https://serverName/webName" to work, since the default port for SSL is 443, you need to change OHS listening port from 4443 to 443 inside ssl.conf

Comment: Could you share more on changing 4443 to 443? In ssl.conf, I manually change Listen serverName:4443 to Listen serverName:443, but it is not working. My OS is Windows, does it matter? As most of the resources I found is for UNIX system only.

Comment: ssl.conf usually has the Listen directive and the VirtualHost directive, where one must change, in order to change the ssl listening port. Please be advised that you need to restart apache afterwards.